# Why is my SQL query failing in MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-workbench

I am new in MySQL. I have created two tables, employee with fields Employeeid(PK),Name, Address and order with fields idOrder(PK) and Employeeid.

I am trying to run this simple join query --

```
SELECT * FROM employee JOIN order ON employee.Employeeid = order.Employeeid;
```

However, the select is marked as red and is showing

```
"SELECT" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting: '(', WITH
```

I did some googling and it looks to be a syntax, parsing error, but I am not able to pinpoint the root cause. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try: set order in backticks. ORDER is a KEYWORD and you use it as schemaname

Comment: `order` is a reserved word I believe. Are you able to create the `order` table ? If so, I would suggest to  avoid using such names and give a proper name to it.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Answer (score 1):

`order` is a key word in `MySQL`, you need to escape it by using **`**

```
SELECT e.* FROM employee e JOIN `order` AS o ON e.Employeeid = o.Employeeid;
```